# I am getting no visible @interface while using JSQSystemSoundPlayer in Objective-C with Swift

Tags: objective-c, xcode, swift, jsqmessagesviewcontroller

I am getting this error:

> /: No visible @interface for 'JSQSystemSoundPlayer' declares the
>   selector 'playAlertSoundWithFilename:fileExtension:'

I am creating a chat app with `JSQMessagesViewController`.
Here is the code:

```
if (asAlert) {
    [[JSQSystemSoundPlayer sharedPlayer] playAlertSoundWithFilename:fileName fileExtension:kJSQSystemSoundTypeAIFF];
}
else {
    [[JSQSystemSoundPlayer sharedPlayer] playSoundWithFilename:fileName fileExtension:kJSQSystemSoundTypeAIFF];
}
```

The error is on both, the if and the else statements.
How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey not sure if you got it working yet or not, but you simply have to add a completion handler like so:

```
if (asAlert) {
    [[JSQSystemSoundPlayer sharedPlayer] playAlertSoundWithFilename:fileName fileExtension:kJSQSystemSoundTypeAIFF completion:nil];

} else {
    [[JSQSystemSoundPlayer sharedPlayer] playSoundWithFilename:fileName fileExtension:kJSQSystemSoundTypeAIFF completion:nil];
}
```

I patched it on github if you don't feel like digging through the code:

https://github.com/FridayDevGroup/JSQMessagesViewController